# Android studio how to center image view in constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I want to center images in Constraint Layout
I use 0dp to all objects (fill constraint), especially this one.
So center-horizontal don't work, gravity don't exist. I don't have an idea how to do this, help me please.
There is a grey background, a text and a guy image in every object. 2 ImageViee and 1 Textview [showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcsK6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

add these in to the item xml, this can make it center horizontal,

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

you can use the following to make it vertically center

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```